# Which control to choose for showing a popup in sharepoint coding

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, popup

I have a requirement like show the popup window(may similar like people picker window) when we click on the search button. That popup should contain a text box and when ever we enter text and click on search then the results should come in the same popup in a table from data base. I thought to do in asp.net popups like `window.open`. But came to know that these are not preferred way. Shall I go for jquery to display results. Will it be much more complex? I am not asking the entire solution. I am asking what is the best way to do it. With Asp.net or Jquery? If in jquery can you give me any hint to how to achieve. I am developing this for sharepoint project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint's ModalDialog framework for managing things like this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

- Create your page (application page, web part page, etc...) that contains your search button and results.
- Add a link or button that calls a ModalDialog function to open this page in a modal window.
- It also supports returning values back to the original page.

Here is an example:

```
function OpenInModal() {
    var options = {
        url: "{The URL to your page},
        title: "Search",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        width: 625,
        height: 525,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: silentCallback
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {

}

function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Operation Successful!');
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **JqueryUI Dialogue Box**.

[dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

add required `input` box inside the div which is going to popup.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
//textbox with search button box
</div>
```

you can modify the div and with the help of jquery you can make changes to showing popup.

Comment: Thanks milind... but how to pass the value from popup to the main page? Rather I want to execute query from database and want to show here.

Comment: @Mihir: You can fetch the data of div using jquery and then append it to DOM present in main page. that'll solve the problem of passing data from popup to main page. and you can also append the result of query from database to div using jquery .